# Retraction of a closed orientable surface onto a simple closed curve

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $S$ be a closed, orientable surface and
$\gamma$ a simple closed curve on $S$. 
Show that $S$ retracts onto $\gamma$ if and only if $\gamma$
represents a non-trivial element in homology.

Clearly, if $[\gamma]=0$ in $H_1(S)$, the composition
$H_1(\gamma) \rightarrow H_1(S) \rightarrow H_1(\gamma)$ can not
be the identity. If the class of $\gamma$ is non-zero, 
how can we construct such retraction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use "change of coordinates principle". this is an easy consequence of the classification of surfaces with a boundary, it principle states:

*If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are any two nonseparating simple closed curves in a surface $S$, then there is a homeomorphism $\phi : S \to S$ with $\phi(\alpha)=\beta$.*

therefore, you may asume that given curve is a meridian. then you can construct "pinch" map from $S$ to a torus, such that your curve maps to the meridian of this torus, and then retract torus to the circle.

Comment: Could you or anyone describe what this pinch map could be?

Comment: @user135520 you should present the surface as the connected sum of a torus and a surface of genus $g-1$; then just collapse the second summand.